# Why is sharepoint 2010 targeting .Net version 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint

Whenever I have an error on my page it prints out the .Net and ASP versions being used. It says:

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5446; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420
```

Why is it targeting 2.0 and how can I change it to use 3.5?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: There is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that for the purposes of asp.net, 3.5 is just a set of extensions for the 2.0 runtime.  So 3.5-based sites still show 2.0 here, because they are running in a 2.0 app pool. If you have 3.5 code you need, it should work just fine here.

Comment: But you need it to run the C# 3 compiler

Comment: The release timeframes didn't work out to get SharePoint 2010 built on .NET 4.0. Our in-house SharePoint guy, who's always up on the latest, has said that it is slated for use in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change what SharePoint's DLLs are targeting. That being said, there is no point. Any code that you add to the GAC can be in 3.5. If you write an app to pull/push data to a SharePoint site, you can use 3.5. You gain nothing by trying to switch the .Net version that SharePoint is targeting.